# How to visualize MuMax3 shapes?

Tags: magnetism, visualization-software, mumax3

I'm new to micromagnetics and the finite difference method. The [mumax3 software](https://mumax.github.io/) lets you create a variety of geometric shapes. I would like to create a core-shell particle to study magneto-electric effects. Is there a way to visualize the geometry created in mumax3. More specifically I would like a software similar to VMD etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a site with a web-app interface called [MuMax-view](http://dynamag.ugent.be/mumax-view/). But inorder to view the geometries, the initial shape should be created, set as the geometry and saved. Running that file results in a geom*.ovf file which could be opened in the web-app.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: +1. Thanks for figuring out the answer to your question and sharing it in case it's useful to future users!

Answer (score 3):

The web-app interface (Mumax-View) mentioned in the previous answer is fine. However, you could try to use "Muview" locally on your computer. You could find the software [here](https://github.com/grahamrow/Muview2/releases). This is a very useful software to visualize the spin configuration of the geometry.